# как определить значение высоты скрола в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть блок wrap с висотой, а i стрелка

```
<div class="wpar">
    <i ...></i>
</div>
```

надо сделать чтоб при скроле значением 100 срабатовало `hide()` для `<i>`

Answer (score 1):

Свойство [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) считывает или устанавлиет количество пикселей, прокрученных от верха элемента. scrollTop измеряет дистанцию от верха элемента до верхней точки видимого контента. Когда контент элемента не создаёт вертикальную прокрутку, его scrollTop равно 0.

```js
const wpar = document.querySelector('.wpar')

wpar.onscroll = (e) => {
  const { scrollTop } = wpar
  
  document.querySelector('#example-info').textContent = scrollTop
  
  if (scrollTop > 100)
    document.querySelector('#example-info').textContent = `hide, scrollTop > 100 (${scrollTop})`
}
```

```css
.example-el {
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}

.wpar {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<span id="example-info">Начните скролить</span>

<div class="wpar">
  <div class="example-el"></div>
</div>
```